# DRC errors in Eagle design

Tags: eaglecad, error, drc

I am a new Eagle user.  While trying to create a simple adapter between two connectors, I receive many DRC errors (overlaps, clearance, dimensions.  The libraries of the connectors were downloaded from the manufacturers' websites.  This specific connector is Omnetics A79022-001; here's the link to Digikey - digikey.co.il/en/products/detail/omnetics/A79022-001/13549083 and to the manufacturer - omnetics.com/products/neuro-connectors/nano-strip-connectors; and the SnapEDA -snapeda.com/parts/A79026-001/Omnetics/view-part.
What I am doing wrong here?

I created my own library.  The footprint looks OK, there are no overlaps:[image].  However, when I am creating a board, I see the overlaps again: [image]  Am I missing something here?

[image])
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer's library is clearly wrong: all the pads (green filled areas) overlap, as the DRC is confirming. You either need to get the correct model from the manufacturer or, more likely, just make your own - it's a good skill to have anyway, as you'll definitely need it.

Comment: Actually, it was a STEP file that I found on the manufacturer's site and uploaded to Eagle as a library.  It probably does not have the pads of the connector.

Comment: See if you can find the actual layout library (unlikely, most vendors still only do Altium libraries) - whatever you've done to import it has not worked as all the pads are overlapping. Do you have a link to the part?

Comment: Yes, here's the link to Digikey - https://www.digikey.co.il/en/products/detail/omnetics/A79022-001/13549083 and to the manufacturer (the part number is A79022-001) - https://www.omnetics.com/products/neuro-connectors/nano-strip-connectors; and the SnapEDA -https://www.snapeda.com/parts/A79026-001/Omnetics/view-part/

Comment: You'll need to make your own footprint - helpful if you could add a link to the product in the original question too :)

Comment: I added the links to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the pads of the footprint of the library that I downloaded do not overlap.  However, when I add a connector's symbol to the board, the pads are overlapping.

Comment: I created my own library.  On the footprint, there are no visible overlaps.  However, when I create the board, I see many overlaps.  I added the pictures to the question.  Is there anything that I am doing wrong?